# Angular universal showing only CSS imports without HTML content or even meta tags

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I've recetly added @nguniversal/express-engine to my angular app, it does only display CSS imports. I've set some meta descriptions tags in each component (PAGE) to optimize the app for the crawler, but i'm not able to see them in view-source neither the HTML content. Here is a screen shot of the view-source.
[image: View Source]

i haven't tweaked the initial updates performed by @nguniversal/express-engine.
I'm expecting to see html content and the meta tags that i've set on each page view-source.
There is my SSR set up :
**app.server.module.ts :**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**app.module.ts : **

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.server.ts : **

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Initialize the server environment - for example, adding DOM built-in types to the global scope.
 *
 * NOTE:
 * This import must come before any imports (direct or transitive) that rely on DOM built-ins being
 * available, such as `@angular/elements`.
 */
import '@angular/platform-server/init';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

**server.ts : **

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/DiarAlkhibra/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: Do you see red errors in the console where you ran `npm run dev:ssr` or `npm run start:ssr`? What backend stack are you using?

Comment: yes it says : """1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  legend+* -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') """ And am using express.

Comment: Look for `.type` in your project and try to assess where an object may be `undefined`. Then you can just wrap it in an `<ng-container *ngIf="!!blabla"></ng-container>`

Comment: it's far from being the solution i think, because after doing a research, it's a bootstrap related warning, it dose have anything to do with this problem. i don't know if SSR is working or not because in one hand i can see CSS imports that are not shown initialy if using "ng serve" but in the other hand i can't see the HTML content pre-rendred.

Comment: Yes that's all consequences of errors during SSR. You need to ensure that no errors pop up during SSR, then html will be rendered, and styles (should be) too (if you're on angular 12 or higher...)